# Write a delegate for a class in swift

Tags: swift, delegates

I have the following class:

```
protocol ShowAlertDelegate {
    func showAlert(sim:String, msg:String)
}

class MyLocationManager: CLLocationManager, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var shareModel : LocationShareModel
    func locationManager(locationManager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
    }

...
}
```

I define an instance of this class in `MyViewContoller`, but since the `locationManager` function is implemented in `MyLocationManager`, I write:

```
myLocationManager.delegate = myLocationManager
```

However, I need to show alerts to the user if sth goes wrong in `MyLocationManager`. To do this, I can write the function to `showAlerts` in `MyViewContoller` class, but then I cannot write any more 
`myLocationManager.delegate = self`, in `MyViewContoller`!

Any suggestion how to access this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `alertDelegate` property to `MyLocationManager`:

```
class MyLocationManager: CLLocationManager, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var shareModel : LocationShareModel
    weak var alertDelegate: ShowAlertDelegate?

    func locationManager(locationManager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
        alertDelegate?.showAlert("Hello", msg: "World")
    }
}
```

And assign it in `MyViewController`:

```
myLocationManager.delegate = myLocationManager
myLocationManager.alertDelegate = self
```

`MyViewController` have to adopt `ShowAlertDelegate` protocol.

Also if you want to move code that works with `CLLocationManager` in separate class then it's better to use composition not inheritance:

```
class MyLocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    private let locationManager: CLLocationManager
    weak var alertDelegate: ShowAlertDelegate?

    init(locationManager: CLLocationManager) {
        self.locationManager = locationManager
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    func locationManager(locationManager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
        alertDelegate?.showAlert("Hello", msg: "World")
    }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks. I did not thought I can always define a new delegate!